# Uniformity in convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n(1-x),~~x \in [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the series of functions$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n(1-x),~~x \in [0,1].$$
It seems to me the convergence of the series to the function $f(x)=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ is uniform. But I couldn't deal with the convergence in maximum norm $\|f_n-f\|_{\infty}=\sup_{x \in[0,1]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\sup_{x \in[0,1]}|\frac{(-x)^n+(-x)^{2+n}-1+x}{1+x}|$ to prove the uniformity in convergence. Any approach through $\epsilon-\delta$ condition?

Comment: You can pull out the factor $1-x$ and get a simple geometric series.

Comment: $f_n$ does not converge to $f$. It is $f_1+f_2+...+f_n$ which converges to $f$. Compute $f_1+f_2+...+f_n$ first/

Comment: How to say the convergence of  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n$ to $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$ is uniform on $[0,1]$?

Comment: How to say the partial sum $f_0+f_1+f_2+...+f_{n-1}=\frac{1-(-x)^n}{1-x}$ converges to $\frac{1}{1+x}$ uniformely on $[0,1]$?